# How to remove addEventListner?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, event

Using this to close the modal when escape button pressed in salesforce aura component.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            var kcode = event.code;
            if (kcode == 'Escape') {
                 functionToCloseModal();
             }
        });
```

But for all modal functionToCloseModal() this same function executed. Need to know how to remove this addEventListner() function when that specific modal is closed.

Answer (score 2):

To use `removeEventListener` it is essential to keep a reference to the function that was originally registered using `addEventListener`. You will need to do something like:

```
const listener = function (event) {
            var kcode = event.code;
            if (kcode == 'Escape') {
                 functionToCloseModal();
             }
        };

component.set("v.listener", listener);

document.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
```

then later:

```
const listener = component.get("v.listener");

document.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
```

In LWCs you need to bind the event listener function to ensure "this" is appropriate. I'm not sure if you have to do that in Aura components too.

Answer (score 0):

We have `removeEventListener()` method in JavaScript.The `removeEventListener()` is an inbuilt function in JavaScript which removes an event handler from an element for a attached event.for example, if a button is disabled after one click you can use removeEventListener() to remove a click event listener.

```
element.removeEventListener(event, listener, useCapture)
```

**Parameters**: It accepts three parameters which are specified below-

1. event: It is a string which describes the name of event that has to be remove.
2. listener: It is the function of the event handler to remove.
3. useCapture: It is an optional parameter. By default it is Boolean value false which specifies the removal of event handler from the bubbling phase and if it is true than the removeEventListener() method removes the event handler from the capturing phase.